# Which of the following is a data mining task?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, data-mining

Which of the following is a data mining task? Select one:

A. Search Google for “Indian National Flag”.

B. Giving a 100% correct prognosis of the future success or failure for a new business.

C. Grouping search results by theme of the results.

To the extend I have understood about DM I have given option B as the answer. But I am not sure about my choice so i am writing here to get the actual right answer.

Comment: I've added the `self-study` tag. Please review its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score 3):

A. Yes this is a data mining task if you are filtering the results. But you will also need computer vision with a data mining algorithm to see which is the flag and which is not.

B. This can be a data mining problem depending on what variables you are using. But you CANNOT have a 100% prognosis because of the impacts of improbable events.

C. This is a classification problem using machine learning. IF you consider machine learning data mining then yes it is a data mining task